# Formik pass customized Props to custom Field Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

Good evening everyone,
I am having a small issue with custom Formik Fields..

I am using an own custom `Field` such as:

```
<Field name="pdfFile" component={FileUpload} />
```

FileUpload Props look like:

```
interface FileUploadProps {
    field: FieldInputProps<any>; //These props should probably be derived from Formik
    form: FormikProps<any>;
    width: string;
    height: string;
}
```

field and form are correctly passed into the component, but how can I pass width and height into the component? Tried it like, but without success.

```
<Field 
    name="pdfFile" 
    component={(props: any) => (
        <FileUpload
            field={props.field}
            form={props.form}
            width={pdfWidth}
            height={pdfHeight}
        />
    )} 
/>
```

Formik API unfortunately doesn't mention how to solve this problem. Has anyone experienced similar issues and knows how to resolve this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you pass a prop to `Field` that isn't used in `Field`, it will be passed to the component in the `component` prop.

So you can do it like

```
<Field 
    name="pdfFile" 
    width={pdfWidth}
    height={pdfHeight}
    component={FileUpload} 
/>
```

and get the value in the component props

```
const FileUpload = (props) => {
    // props.width
    // props.height
    return ( /* ... */ )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unsure why I didn't give this a shot, works flawlessly :)